# Set date of jDateChooser - null value produced

Tags: java, database, jdatechooser

I'm getting data from Microsoft Access and reading it into an object array and then displaying it on a list. I'm trying to set the date of a jDateChooser using the String from the object. The first time I try to set the date, nothing is set/selected. If I change the date on my GUI, save it to access and try to set the date again, then it works? Not sure why this is the case. Please help (:

```
String apUpdateDate = appointments[appointmentPos].getAppointmentDate(); 
try 
{
     Date updateDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(apUpdateDate);
} 
catch (ParseException ex) 
{
     Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: In the code which you have posted, I can't see anywhere you have set the date to jdatechooser.

Comment: hmmmm... This awkward. - I can see that now (: - Sorry for the inconvenience. This for my school's project so you just helped me fix a silly, but irritating problem. Thank you very much Arvind